# Mercurial: Indicating that a branch has passed testing?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, workflow, dvcs

I am working on establishing a workflow at my company if we were to migrate to DVCS (most likely Mercurial).  One of the things I would like to do is to have a repository for QA.  The idea being that each developer works on a branch and when they are done the branch is pushed to QA.  From there the test team can do their testing and report back any bugs.  Once the branch is fully tested and acceptable it will be pushed to a staging repository where the merge back to the mainline will happen before pushing to the central repository.

This can work quite easily if everyone just communicates the status of their work in some way, but I know this doesn't always happen as you would want it to.  What I am worried about is branches in the QA repo waiting around but nobody knows if it is waiting to be tested, currently being tested, waiting for fixes, waiting to be pushed to the staging area etc.  So what I am looking for are ideas of how a status can be added to a branch?  What would also be good would be to do it in a way that we could use hooks to also notify people of changes in the status.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you need a different system to keep track of this part of your workflow.

A repository consists of things that aren't supposed to change all willy nilly, yet the current Q&A status will by necessity change orthogonal to the contents of the repository.

Let me rephrase that. You have 10 changesets in the Q&A repository, ready to be tested. Exactly what each tester focuses on, the status of each test, etc. will change, even though those 10 changesets stay the same.

I would definitely try to use a bugtracking system where you can integrate the repository history in some way, even if it is just by linking an issue in the system to its changeset.

I notice your comment about not getting support for buying Kiln, but there are other systems you should be able to integrate that would give you something similar.

I would very much resist trying to press Mercurial into service of something it wasn't built to support, trying to use tags for this would fail miserably, and bookmarks would give you problems, as you've already noted.

So again, try to find a separate system for keeping track of Q&A status.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method might be to keep a metadata file in your repo's root folder, named `.teststatus` or somesuch, that looks like:

```
# branch-name, last passed revision
default, 0123456789ab
stable, 0123456789ac
bobs-dev-branch, 0123456789ad
marys-dev-branch, none
```

Using tags or bookmarks would feel like a sort of abuse, here. You couldn't use the same tag across branches (e.g. `passed` would have to be `stable-passed`), and tags are generally not moving. Bookmarks, on the other hand, are intended to move, but you still have the branch-namespacing issues.

Comment: There is an extension for doing exactly this, and it's simple enough to adapt for the OP's exact use case: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FileReviewExtension and https://bitbucket.org/romanz/hgcr/src/bfd3a7d6dced/filereview.py

Answer (score 0):

Joel Spolsky, one of the founders of this site, produces a program called [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) that is integrated with Mercurial and makes it easy to keep track of everyone's status.

Comment: Unfortunaely getting my company to pay for FogBugz would be like getting blood out of a stone.  But you have given me the thought that we could just use Bugzilla to track the status.  Each branch should already be linked to a bug (whether it is actually a defect or a feature etc.) so we could add an extra field in Bugzilla indicating the status.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how your workflow works, but here are a few ideas:

1. [Tags](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag).
2. Use [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches) and [close the branch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) when tested.Typing `hg branches` will show you which branches are still pending.

You could probably use an [incoming hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) for the automatic notification of new changesets being added to the QA repo.

Comment: I had thought about tags, I just wasn't sure about keeping so many tags around.  Would a tag be set on the tip of the branch indicating its status and then updated whenever the status changes?  Or would you have to create a new tag each time the status changed?  Could we push from the QA repo to the staging repo (where the merge happens) without the tag going with it (i.e. the tag only exists in the QA repo)?

Comment: What actually happens to a branch when it is closed?  Can it still be updated? Can it at least be merged back to the mainline?  Or is the closing done as part of the merge (in which case, I guess the merge is already an indication that the branch has been tested).

Comment: The main effect closing has is to remove it from the branches and heads lists. You can still merge the branch, update to it, and you can even commit to it again, which has the effect of re-opening the branch.

Comment: Re:tags - Yes, there would be tags sitting around all over.  They are nice for some things, but they do tend to clutter your repository if they are used too much.

Comment: FWIW, I don't really feel too good about either of my suggestions.  I like what you are trying to do, but can't think of a good solution. If I were you, I think I would do a little more digging with tags and how you might strip them out before pushing them to another repository.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a developer push something to a QA repository if it wasn't ready to be QA'd?  I think the act of pushing changesets to a QA designated repository should be the signal that the feature is ready to be tested.

Feature [branches by cloning](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-clones) is my favorite approach.

Comment: Yes, that is quite obvious, but not the only use case.  What happens when the tester finds an issue and reports it back to the developer.  The branch still exists in the QA repo but it is actually waiting for the developer to make a fix before testing can restart. So we need some way of indicating this to other testers who might be looking for something to start testing.